# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str - loading strings from a list

Tags: python

So I have a list of strings I want to make = 999

```
with open ("Inventory.txt", 'r') as i:
    for items in i:
        item = GetItemID(items)
        PositionOfItems[items]=HERO_INVENTORY_POS
```

`HERO_INVENTORY_POS is = 999`, but I get the error displayed above, if I'm missing anything else require please tell me.

This is the code I used for spawning an item so I kinda just tried to recreate that.`

```
ItemRequest = input("Which item would you like?").upper()
    for i in ItemList:
        if i == ItemRequest:
            ItemRequest = GetItemID(ItemRequest)
            PositionOfItems[ItemRequest]=HERO_INVENTORY_POS`
```

Answer (score 2):

If `PositionOfItems` is a list, then `items` needs to be in an integer. Right now, it's a string, because you're reading it from a file.

Try:

```
    PositionOfItems[int(items)]=HERO_INVENTORY_POS
```

Alternatively, maybe you intended to index the list with `item` and not `items`? In which case you should do

```
    PositionOfItems[item]=HERO_INVENTORY_POS
```

Comment: Ok yeah I noticed my error there, now when it loops through it always comes back with key and adds that to inv no matter what is in the file, the ItemID thing is meant to put the item into it's specific ID

Answer (score 0):

Depending in how you defined `PositionOfItems`

In your line of code

```
PositionOfItems[items]=HERO_INVENTORY_POS
```

You are treating it as a **dictionary** instead of a **list**, where `items` is the key and `HERO_INVENTORY_POS` is the value. When I tried reproducing your code snippet(below), my error was that the dictionary was not defined as empty before its use, and if defined as a list I received the `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`.

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    dict = {} #This line
    for item in f:
        dict[item] = 999
        print item,
```

If you have assigned `PositionOfItems` as a **list**, then the issue is that you would be referring to indexes that have not been defined (or at least not show in your code here) and are attempting to reference them with a string (`items`) instead of an integer. (Giving you the TypeError)